# error on url object not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I have just installed XAMPP on my machine, and when trying to access sub folders in htdocs I get the following error.

Object not found! The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the structure of your htdocs directory as well as the URL you are entering when you get the 404 error please.

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Webeeshop\public and url:http://localhost:8081/en